# Python scikit-learn: Cannot clone object... as the constructor does not seem to set parameter

Tags: python, numpy, copy, scikit-learn

I modified the [BernoulliRBM](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neural_network/rbm.py) class of scikit-learn to use groups of softmax visible units. In the process, I added an extra Numpy array `visible_config` as a class attribute which is initialized in the constructor as follows using:

```
self.visible_config = np.cumsum(np.concatenate((np.asarray([0]),
                                visible_config), axis=0))
```

where `visible_config` is a Numpy array passed as an input to the constructor. The code runs without errors when I directly use the `fit()` function to train the model. However, when I use the `GridSearchCV` structure, I get the following error

```
Cannot clone object SoftmaxRBM(batch_size=100, learning_rate=0.01, n_components=100, n_iter=100,
  random_state=0, verbose=True, visible_config=[ 0 21 42 63]), as the constructor does not seem to set parameter visible_config
```

This seems to be a problem in the equality check between the instance of the class and its copy created by [sklearn.base.clone](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/base.py) because `visible_config` does not get copied correctly. I'm not sure how to fix this. It says in the documentation that `sklearn.base.clone` uses a `deepcopy()`, so shouldn't `visible_config` also get copied? Can someone please explain what I can try here? Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to tell exactly what goes wrong, but you are violating a scikit-learn API convention here. The constructor in an estimator should *only* set attributes to the values the user passes as arguments. All computation should occur in `fit`, and if `fit` needs to store the result of a computation, it should do so in an attribute with a trailing underscore (`_`). This convention is what makes `clone` and meta-estimators such as `GridSearchCV` work.

(*) If you ever see an estimator in the main codebase that violates this rule: that would be a bug, and patches are welcome.

Comment: You're right. Thanks! Removing the computation step and passing the pre-computed `visible config` into the constructor fixed the problem.

Comment: Anyone else trying this...  make sure you're not cloning your model in the __init__.  For example `class NewAlgo(baseestimator, otherestimator): def __init__(sefl,model): self.model = clone(model)` dont do that <--

Comment: I ran into this issue with xgboost and RandomizedSearchCV where my grid had a typo/deprecated parameter in it