# Using OneVsRestClassifier from sklearn to tune a customized binary classification into a multi-class classification

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have binary classification method name **FMclassifier** I need to apply it on a multi-class classification problem, so far I know it is possible to use some estimators to turn a binary classifier or a regressor into a multiclass classifier.
I was wondering if this goal can be reached using **OneVsRestClassifier** in **sklearn** ?
 If so, I need to know how can I apply it in my code? is something like the following code a right way?

```
OneVsRestClassifier(FMClassifier(n_iter=100)).fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would be something like

```
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(MyClassifier(param1 = A, param2 = B))
classifier.fit(X_train, Y)
predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

You just need to ensure that your classifier implements  fit and one of decision_function or predict_proba methods. More info on it here:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html

In your example you use OneVsOneClassifier, this is a different meta-classifier with different approach.

Comment: Thank you so much I am following the same way and I am facing an error: `RuntimeError: Cannot clone object MyClassifiication` it seems like the constructor does not seem to set a parameter but I have set the value for that parameter,  Do you think if error is related to **OneVsRestClassifier** or it should have another reason?

Comment: I think there is some issue with your implementation of MyClassifier - it not fully satisfies the expectations of OneVsRestClassifier. Or even with the way you implemented it at all. I strongly recommend you to check that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510510/python-scikit-learn-cannot-clone-object-as-the-constructor-does-not-seem-to

Comment: yes you are right in fact it doesn't have any **decision_function** and its core only accept **{1,-1}** as **class labels** !! do you think if I define a customized **predict_proba** which can fit my data to the classifier can solve the problem in my case? or it is more complicated than what I think?

Comment: If you properly implement the predict_proba and fit functions it should be enough.Of course, you need to be careful to not violate the SKLearns API (which is mentioned in the link I provided)

Answer (score 1):

In sklearn, OneVsOneClassifier and OutputCodeClassifier are also available other than OneVsRestClassifier.
FYR: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html.

Comment: yes I have also tried others but I have the same error in all cases !