# Scikit-learn Cannot clone object ​*, as the constructor does not seem to set parameter *​ in VotingClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, sentiment-analysis

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510510/python-scikit-learn-cannot-clone-object-as-the-constructor-does-not-seem-to), but without posting relevant code.

I'm trying to create a VotingClassifier based on the Scikit-learn VotingClassifier. FYI the SGD, Bernoulli and MaxEnt classifiers are SKLearn classifiers that are made on the same training and test data, using Scikit's GridSearchCV.

However, I'm getting a RuntimeError when trying to fit the classifier.

[Here's the main program script](https://gist.github.com/jonasft/7b60e53ead18b504ec3913c976688b5a), and the error I get is at the bottom of the post.

Here are github gists for the [lexicon_transformer](https://gist.github.com/jonasft/b57edc86d582cd0f7a13d9e3d01e1f8f) and the [neg_transformer](https://gist.github.com/jonasft/d29221ef3c09f720068513c1dae49681).

My directory structure is like this:

- src\

  - main.py
  - \transformers\

    - negcount_transformer.py
    - lexicon_transformer.py ...
  - \data\pickles\

    - sgd.pickle
    - bernoulli.pickle ...

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "main_combination.py", line 183, in 
>      eclf.fit(X_train,y_train)
>
> File "C:\Users\x\python_projects\tsa\classifiers\ensemble_classifier.py", line 147, in fit
>      self.clfs_ = [clone(clf) for clf in self.clfs]
>
> File "C:\Users\x\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 51, in clone
>      new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)
>
> File "C:\Users\x\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 39, in clone
>      return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
>
> File "C:\Users\x\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 39, in clone
>      return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
>
> File "C:\Users\x\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 51, in clone
>      new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)
>
> File "C:\Users\x\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 39, in clone
>      return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
>
> File "C:\Users\x\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 39, in clone
>      return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
>
> File "C:\Users\x\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 105, in clone
>      (estimator, name))
>
> RuntimeError: Cannot clone object NegTransformer(norm=True), as the constructor does not seem to set parameter norm