# Scikit : custom estimator : cannot clone

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have written my own estimator for automated cleaning of a particular dataset. I think I followed the scikit rules correctly :

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

class cleaning(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, to_drop = [], ins_threshold=0.6, 
                 corr_threshold=0.7, attribute_filepath='attribute.xlsx'): # no *args or **kargs, provides methods get_params() and set_params()
        """
        Parameters:
        -----------
        to_drop (list) : columns to be dropped
        ins_thresholrd (float) : [0.0 - 1.0] insignificant threshold above which columns containing that proportion of NaN get dropped
        corr_threshold (float) : [0.0 - 1.0] correlation threshold above which correlated columns get dropped (first one is kept)
        attribute_filepath (str of pathlib.Path) : path to the Excel file containing attributes information

        """

        self.attribute_filepath = Path(attribute_filepath)
        self.ins_threshold = ins_threshold
        self.corr_threshold = corr_threshold

        self.to_drop = to_drop
        self.ins_col = None
        self.correlated_col = None
```

But I still receive the error

```
RuntimeError: Cannot clone object cleaning(attribute_filepath=PosixPath('MyFile.xlsx')), as the constructor either does not set or modifies parameter attribute_filepath
```

I don't understand why since `self.attribute_filepath`  is clearly defined in my `__init__` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though very late, I'll try to give an answer as I ran into a similar problem. For me, you're kind of violating scikit-learn API convention here as you're setting `self.attribute_filepath` to something which is different from the default argument.
Indeed, speaking about the `__init__`'s method and quoting the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#apis-of-scikit-learn-objects):

> There should be no logic, not even input validation, and the parameters should not be changed. The corresponding logic should be put where the parameters are used, typically in fit. The following is wrong:

```
def __init__(self, param1=1, param2=2, param3=3):
    # WRONG: parameters should not be modified
    if param1 > 1:
        param2 += 1
    self.param1 = param1
    # WRONG: the object's attributes should have exactly the name of
    # the argument in the constructor
    self.param3 = param2
```

What happens otherwise when passing your custom transformer to `GridSearchCV()` - I guess you are passing your transformer to a `Pipeline` and this in turn to `GridSearchCV()` or perhaps you are doing something similar - and consequently calling `fit()` on the obtained instance, would be the following:

1. Your setting could potentially give no problem until you reach [this point](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/42aff4e2edd8e8887478f6ff1628f27de97be6a3/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L876). Then:
2. Your transformer will be cloned (and the `__init__` method called);
3. The setter will be called;
4. The outer clone will fail [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/42aff4e2edd8e8887478f6ff1628f27de97be6a3/sklearn/base.py#L84) as `the constructor [...] modifies parameter attribute_filepath`.

Quoting the docs again,

> As model_selection.GridSearchCV uses set_params to apply parameter setting to estimators, it is essential that calling set_params has the same effect as setting parameters using the **init** method.

Of course, some portions of the answer rely on some educated guesses.

This [post](https://www.mbrouns.com/posts/2020-01-26-sklearns-init/) explains this point very well imo. Eventually, I would also suggest these two answers to similar questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510510/python-scikit-learn-cannot-clone-object-as-the-constructor-does-not-seem-to) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64945380/runtimeerror-cannot-clone-object-scikit-learn-custom-estimator).